# Wrong sprite is destroyed in Unity (DontDestroyOnLoad)

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, singleton, monodevelop

I have a problem where I'm changing the Image of a `SpriteRenderer` as a onClick method is called.

However I had a problem of duplicates in the Scene after reloading it (i.e going out of the scene and then back again).

I have tried solving this by destroying the correct duplicate when reentering the scene. However, the old (changed) sprite (the one I would like to keep) keeps getting destroyed while the new one is still there.

This is part of my code for saving and destroying the sprite:

```
private void saveSprite(Clue c){
        markedObjects.Add(c);
        Debug.Log ("Save");
        DontDestroyOnLoad (c.getSprite());
        create = true;
}

private void destroySprite(Clue c){
    foreach(Clue g in markedObjects){
        print (g);
        if (!markedObjects.Contains(c)){
            Debug.Log("Destroy");
            Destroy (c.getSprite());
        }
    }
}
```

I really don't understand how the destroySprite condition `!markedObjects.Contains(c)` can be passed while still destroying the incorrect sprite.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give more info like: what does the print(g); line returns. Do you have all the object you expect in this list?
When do you call these two functions?

Comment: What is `Clue`? No one knows what this is. Your code is not enough to get help.

Comment: is `markedObjects` declared as a static? When is destroySprite called? For your second question: To safely delete while iterating try to access the elements in a for-loop, which goes from the last element to the first. Thus you will have no iterator issues and can safely delete items without worrying about wrong indices.

Answer (score 0):

private void destroySprite(Clue c){ <-- I assume Clue c is the sprite you want to destroy

```
foreach(Clue g in markedObjects){ <-- get each Clue in markedObjects
    print (g);
    if (!markedObjects.Contains(c)){ <-- if c is not within all of markedObjects then destroy c? Perhaps you meant to destroy g.
        Debug.Log("Destroy");
        Destroy (c.getSprite()); 
    }
}
```

}